# C++ String utility functions - Code check

Tags: c++, strings

I am trying to create a string class without `std::string`. Just for educational purpose.

So I created some utility functions, and it would be very nice if you guys could take a look at the code for mistakes.

Does anyone see any errors? (probably)

````cpp
// Includes.
#include <iostream> // for "print()" and "std".
#include <sstream> // for "tostr()".

// Print.
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
void print(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args) {
    std::cout << std::forward<Arg>(arg);
    ((std::cout << ' ' << std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

// Allocate a new array.
template <class T>
T * alloc(
    // The new size of the array.
    size_t n
) {
    T *a;
    a = (T *) malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(T));
    return a;
}

// Delete.
template <class T>
void del(T *x) {
    delete[] x;
    x = NULL;
}

// Length.
size_t len(const char* x) {
    return ::strlen(x);
}
size_t len(char x) {
    if (std::isblank(x)) { return 0; }
    return 1;
}

// Cast const char* to char *.
char* strcast(const char* x, size_t n = -1) {
    char *s;
    if (n == -1) { n = len(x); }
    s = alloc<char>(n); // real alloc size afterwards is n + 1
    if (n == 0) { 
        s[0] = '\0';
        return s; 
    }
    return strcat(strcpy(s, x), "");
}

// String is null.
// Will cause segmentation fault if x is unallocated [const char x;], when x is [const char *x = ""] it will run.
bool strnull(const char* x) {
    return (x == NULL || ! *x);
}

// Safely dump a string.
// Not necessary.
// Will cause segmentation fault if x is [const char x;], when x is [const char *x = ""] it will run.
// const char* strdump(const char* x) {
//     return x;
// }
// char* strdump(char* x) {
//     return x;
// }

// String equals.
// Will again cause segfault if x / y is unallocated [const char x;].
bool streq(const char* x, const char* y) {
    return strcmp(x, y) == 0;
}

// Char equals.
// Does not cause segfault if a / b is unallocated [char x].
bool chareq(char a, char b) {
    if (std::isspace(a) and std::isspace(b)) { return true; }
    return not (a < b) and not (a > b) and a == b;
}

// String from double.
template <class T>
char* tostr(T x) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << x;
    char *y;
    y = ss.str().data();
    return y;
}

// From string to double.
// Will cause segmentation fault if x is unallocated [const char x;], when x is [const char *x = ""] it will run.
float fromstr(const char* x) {
    if (strnull(x)) { return 0; }
    return std::atof(x);
}

// Concatenate multiple char*.
// Will cause segmentation fault if x / y is unallocated [const char x;], when x / y is [const char *x = ""] it will run.
char *strconcat(char *x, const char*y) {
    size_t xn = strlen(x);
    size_t yn = strlen(y);
    char *z = alloc<char>(xn + yn);
    memcpy(z, x, xn);
    memcpy(z + xn, y, yn);
    return z;
}
const char *strconcat(const char *x, const char *y) {
    size_t xn = strlen(x);
    size_t yn = strlen(y);
    char *z = alloc<char>(xn + yn);
    memcpy(z, x, xn);
    memcpy(z + xn, y, yn);
    return z;
}
char *strconcat(char *x) { return x; }
const char *strconcat(const char *x) { return x; }
template <class... Args> char *strconcat(char *x, const char *y, Args&&... args) {  return strconcat(strconcat(x, y), args...); }
template <class... Args> const char *strconcat(const char *x, const char *y, Args&&... args) { return strconcat(strconcat(x, y), args...); }

// Find substring in str.
// Will cause segmentation fault if str / substr is unallocated [const char x;], when str / substr is [const char *x = ""] it will run.
// class npos {
// public:
//  size_t m_pos;
//  bool found = false;
//  npos() {};
//  npos(size_t pos) { m_pos = pos; found = true; }
//  npos(int pos) {  if (pos > 0) { m_pos = pos; found = true; } }
//  operator size_t() { return m_pos; }
// };
class nposclass {
public:
    size_t m_pos;
    nposclass() {}
    operator size_t() { return m_pos; }
};
nposclass npos = nposclass();
size_t strfind(char* str, const char* substr) {
    char *dest = strstr(str, substr);
    if (dest == NULL) { return npos; };
    return dest - str;
}
size_t strfind(char* str, const char* substr, size_t start) {
    size_t i = strfind(str + start, substr);
    if (i != -1) { return start + i; }
    return i;
}

// Replace a substring in a string.
// Will cause segmentation fault if str / from / to is unallocated [const char x;], when str / from / to is [const char *x = ""] it will run.
char* strreplace(char* str, const char* from, const char* to, double increaser = 2.0) {
    if (strnull(from)) { return str; }
    size_t nt = strlen(to); // to size.
    size_t nf = strlen(from); // from size.
    size_t n = strlen(str); // str size.
    size_t mn = n; // max alloc size.
    char *result = alloc<char>(mn);
    size_t nn = 0; // new size.
    while (*str) {

        // Found from.
        if (strstr(str, from) == str) {

            // Check resize.
            if (nn + nt > mn) {
                mn = (nn + nt) * increaser;
                char *a = alloc<char>(mn);
                memcpy(a, result, nn);
                delete[] result; result = NULL;
                result = a;
            }

            // Add to.
            memcpy(&result[nn], to, nt);
            nn += nt;
            str += nf;

        }

        // Add current char.
        else { result[nn++] = *str++; }
    }
    result[nn] = '\0';
    return result;
}


// Testing.
// Test code produces the warnings "ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *'", but that will be fixed by creating a string object.
int main() {

    // strcast.
    const char* x = "Hello";
    char *y = strcast(x);
    print("strcast:",y);

    // strnull.
    const char* x0 = "s ";
    const char* x1 = "";
    print("len: 2 ==>",strnull(x0));    
    print("len: 0 ==>", strnull(x1));    

    // len.
    print("strnull: 0 ==>",strnull(x0));    
    print("strnull: 1 ==>", strnull(x1));       

    // streq.
    print("streq: 0 ==>",streq(x0, x1));    
    print("streq: 1 ==>", streq(x1, x1));    

    // chareq.
    char c;
    print("chareq: 0 ==>", chareq('a', 'b'));    
    print("chareq: 1 ==>",chareq('a', 'a'));    
    print("chareq: 0 ==>",chareq('a', c));    

    // tostr.
    char * y0 = tostr<double>(1.1);
    print("tostr: 1.1 ==>", y0);    

    // fromstr.
    double d0 = fromstr("1.1");
    print("fromstr: 1.1 ==>", d0);   

    // Strconcat.
    const char *x2 = "Hello";
    x2 = strconcat(x2, " World!", " Howdy!");
    print("strconcat: Hello World! Howdy =", x2);
    char *y1 = "Hello";
    y1 = strconcat(y1, " World!", " Howdy!");
    print("strconcat: Hello World! Howdy =", y1); 

    // strfind.
    print("strfind: 4 ==>", strfind("Hello World!", "o"));
    print("strfind: 7 ==>", strfind("Hello World!", "o", 5));
    print("strfind: 1 ==>", strfind("Hello World!", "?") == npos);
    print("strfind: 0 ==>", strfind("Hello World!", "?") == 10);

    // strreplace.
    print("strreplace: Hello Universe! ==>", strreplace("Hello World!", "World", "Universe"));
    print("strreplace: Hello! ==>", strreplace("Hello World!", " World", ""));
    print("strreplace: Hello World! ==>", strreplace("Hello World!", "", ""));

    return 0;
}
```
````

Comment: Don't replace reviewed code. Either post a follow-up, or an answer with list and rationale of what you changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Renaming built-in functions

If you are writing these functions for your own education, then I don't think you should be using built-in functions to implement them.

```cpp
size_t len(const char* x) {
    return ::strlen(x);
}
```

This could be written without any library functions as a `for`-loop using your `len(char)` function (if that's how you want to define the length of your string).

Similarly, these functions also merely rename language built-ins:

- `alloc` just calls `malloc()` with nearly the same arguments (it should call `new`, see below).
- `del` just calls `delete[]`
- `strfind` just calls `strstr()`
- `fromstr` just calls `std::atof`

You should be trying to write your functions without using the language's built-in functions so you can discover how they work. This does not apply to such low-level functions as `malloc` and `delete[]`, but all functions operating on strings are doable.

Write your more complex functions in terms of the simpler functions you've written. You only use your `len()` function once and call `strlen()` everywhere else.

---

```cpp
// String from double.
template <class T>
char* tostr(T x) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << x;
    char *y;
    y = ss.str().data();
    return y;
}
```

Since `ss.str()` creates a `std::string`, this seems to go against the goals of this code.

Another problem with `tostr()` above: the `char` array returned by `.data()` is not null-terminated, so it can't be used with most string functions. You should use `.c_str()`.

And another problem: you are returning the data from a temporary string that will be destroyed at the end of the function. When I run your code, I get the line: `tostr: 1.1 ==> ⁿ⌡»`. I ran it again and got this: `tostr: 1.1 ==> 4≈§☺<►`. The function returns a pointer to destroyed data. You need to allocate space for the resulting string, store the pointer to that data in `y`, copy the new data to that pointer, and then return that pointer to the explicitly allocated data (that is, `y`).

##### Undefined behavior

Your `alloc` and `del` cannot be used together. Memory allocated with `malloc` must be deleted by calling `free`. The operator `delete` should only be used with pointers allocated with `new`. Mixing up these operators leads to undefined behavior, which means the compiler makes no guarantees about what the resulting program will do. Since this is C++, use `new` and `delete`.

---

```cpp
class nposclass {
public:
    size_t m_pos;
    nposclass() {}
    operator size_t() { return m_pos; }
};
```

The member `m_pos` is never assigned a value. Using the class like this is undefined behavior and may or may not function correctly.

Similary, `char c` in `main()` is never assigned a value.

##### Non-compiling code

If you want a function to be able to take a string literal as an argument, then it must take a `const char*`, not a `char*`. String literals cannot be modified. This is also why you cannot call `strreplace` on a string literal in the final lines of your `main()` function.

Functions like `strfind` should take `const char*` because a function that searches a string should not modify the string.

##### Other bits

```cpp
    // strnull.
    const char* x0 = "s ";
    const char* x1 = "";
    print("len: 2 ==>",strnull(x0));    
    print("len: 0 ==>", strnull(x1));
```

You probably meant to test `len()` here, right?

The function `strcast()` is not really a cast. It creates a copy of a string. It should be renamed to reflect this behavior.

In your `chareq()` function, what does `not (a < b) and not (a > b) and a == b` accomplish that `a == b` doesn't?

Also, even though `and`, `not`, and `or` are synonyms for `&&`, `!`, and `||`, respectively, they are very rarely used by C++ programmers. Using these words will cause some programmers to wonder if they opened a Python source file by mistake. :)

In many of your functions, spaces are treated specially, either by not being counted in the length of a `char` as in `len(char)` or by any space character being equal to any other space character--as in `chareq(char, char)`. This should be documented somewhere in the code as a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed & understandable answer! Extremely useful. I just read it and I had already made a lot of changes, some were already fixed. And a lot not lol. What exactly do you mean with _italic_ "length of a char as in len(char) or by any space character being equal to any other space character" _italic_ . I understand what you mean in 'chareq' but not in 'len'. Or do you mean what happens in 'strlen'?

Comment: And I would love to create this without using default functions, though recreating functions as 'strstr' with equal performance is an issue.

Comment: Also another question about the problems with returning a value that has no lifetime. Like I did in the first 'tostr'. How exactly should it work? Like this: somehwere in the function there must be a declaration of a pointer, then point the pointer to the value like `ss.data().c_str()`, and then return the pointer? Is that correct?

Comment: Probably otherwise this code would work.. `// Parse from int / double / float / long / bool.
 template <class T>
 static string parse(T x) {
  char* y;
  y = strduplc(tostr(x));
  return y;
 }` (Also in updated code inside class string)

Comment: About `||` vs `or`, I just like the red color that `or` uses lol, it is not slower right?

Comment: And are there no further mistakes with allocating/deleting memory? That is completely new for me. (Beside using delete[] with malloc, that is fixed)  #spam

Comment: And about the function `tostr` btw. I did create a parse function but I ran into problems when the size of the integer was too large. And couldn't make it work, so i switched to `std::string`. But like you said it completely defeats the purpose of the string class.. So might you have any working code to parse a `double`/`int` to `const char*` then that would be lovely. I also posted about it on stackoverflow but no one had the answer.

Comment: @user260583 Answering your questions in order: My comment on the string length functions is that, since your `len(char)` function defines a blank character has having zero length, I thought your other string length functions would also ignore blank characters. If this is true, then your functions should act consistently. Otherwise, `len(char)` acts differently than `len(char*)` for an unknown reason. Consistency helps readers of your code understand what your program is doing.

Comment: @user260583 It is very likely that the functions you write will not perform as well. The C++ library functions have been under development for decades (even longer than C++ has existed, since many are imported from C). However, figuring out how to write these functions yourself will be good practice. Substring search has a lot of research behind it if you want to learn more advanced algorithms, some of which can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm

Comment: @user260583 One way to solve the lifetime problem would be something like this: `return strcast(s.c_str()); return y`. Your `strcast` function allocates new space for the string result and copies the data. Now, when the string created by `ss.str()` is destroyed, it doesn't take the return value with it.

Comment: @user260583 There is no difference in speed between `||` and `or`. They are exactly the same. The keyword `or` is just part of an unfamiliar dialect.

Comment: @user260583 I don't see anymore mistakes regarding allocating/deallocating, other than `del()` never being called on any created string. I could be wrong, as I try to avoid writing code with `new`/`delete`/`malloc`/`free`.

Comment: @user260583 Yes, `tostr()` is a hard problem since you need to figure out how much space you need before you start. Try doing just integers first, since floats and doubles can have many representations.

Comment: Is there really a need to achieve the same performance? For educational purpose, it's just nice to get it working. You could then compare your implementation to the stdlib one.